# Netcat UDP command not working?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, mojave

From one Terminal:

```
echo "test" | nc -u -l 127.0.0.1 10000
```

From another Terminal:

```
nc -u 127.0.0.1 10000
```

But the Terminal just hangs, it doesnt return the "test" output. It seems to work fine without the `-u` argument. What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have accidentially reversed which one is the listener and which one is not. I.e. you'll need to change the commands to the following:

Open the listener first:

```
nc -u -l 127.0.0.1 10000
```

Then the sender:

```
echo "test" | nc -u 127.0.0.1 10000
```

Then you'll see that the listener outputs "test" on the console.

You can stop the nc program by pressing Ctrl-c.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Strangely, if you use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` nothing happens.